# How do you integrate over a curve in 2D space that is parameterized by a polynomial?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration, polynomials

I have a simple curve in 2D space `(x, y)` that is parameterized by a polynomial as a function of `t` and I would like to know the length of that curve. How do I accomplish that? I looked into `scipy.integrate` and `numpy.polyint` but I didn't manage to find a solution. It seems that both of them are only able to integrate over a 1D polynomial. Here is an example for a curve:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate


x0, y0 = 0.0, 0.0
vx, vy = 0.1, 0.1
ax, ay = -0.0001, 0
coeff = np.array([[ax, ay], [vx, vy], [x0, y0]])

pos = lambda t: np.polyval(coeff, t)
```

Comment: You will need to understand the math first, see [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ParaArcLength.aspx). After that, the implementation in numpy is straightforward.

Comment: Polynomials have analytically obtainable integrals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arc length is a single-variable polynomial on the curve parameter. You need to define the expression for the differential of the arc length and then you'll be able to integrate over it, as explained in [the link in the comments](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ParaArcLength.aspx). As you can see there, it can be simply expressed as the Euclidean norm of the vector `(dx/dt, dy/dt)`. Here is therefore how you can implement it:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy

x0, y0 = 0.0, 0.0
vx, vy = 0.1, 0.1
ax, ay = -0.0001, 0
coeff = np.array([[ax, ay], [vx, vy], [x0, y0]])

# Position expression is not really necessary
pos = lambda t: np.polyval(coeff, t)

# Derivative of the arc length
def ds(t):
    # Coefficients of polynomial derivative
    coeff_d = coeff[:-1] * np.arange(len(coeff) - 1, 0, -1)[:, np.newaxis]
    # Norm of position derivatives
    return np.linalg.norm(np.polyval(coeff_d, np.expand_dims(t, -1)), axis=-1)

# Integrate across parameter interval
t_start, t_end = 0, 1
arc_length, err = scipy.integrate.quad(ds, t_start, t_end)
print(arc_length)
# 0.1413506691471052
```

Of course, you could try to work out the analytical expression of the integral of `ds` and then you wouldn't need any integration method.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Although this doesn't look very straightforward to me. Shouldn't `coeff_d` simply be `np.polyder(coeff)`?

Comment: @mapf Ah, good point, I forgot there was that... although I think that function assumes a single polynomial as input, as I'm not seeing how to use it correctly when you have two polynomials like you do... If you just do `np.polyder(coeff)` the result is `[[-0.0002  0.    ] [ 0.2     0.1   ]]` which is not correct, and `np.polyder(coeff.T)` fails for some reason? You could apply it column-wise I guess.

Comment: Ah I see. It's a bit counter-intuitive that some of these methods work with multi-dimensional polynomials and some don't.

Comment: Different question: what do you need `np.expand_dims(t, -1)), axis=-1` for? If I just put `t` I seem to get the same result?

Comment: @mapf Ah, that's just to make sure `ds` behaves consistently, really... I'm not sure how integration methods are implemented and what they pass to the given function, but the problem is that if you have e.g. `t = [1, 2]` and do `np.polyval(coeff, t)` (to get `x` and `y` values at `1` and `2`) the result is incorrect, you have to give `t = [[1], [2]]`. `np.expand_dims` always adds a singleton dimension at the end, which later is reduced by `np.linalg.norm`, so the polynomial is always evaluated element-wise and the output shape is the same as the input.